# How can I use app.listen when the function is inside a var type variable?

Tags: node.js, express, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to make Autodesk forge web app as presenter web app & viewer web app for VR navigation. I followed the tutorial 'autodesk forge Share Viewer staste with websockets'. (And I learned javascript a little.)

Before, the last line was  `` app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); }); ``

And the tutorial want me to adjust some additional lines to that line. code(it doesn't work) - start.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const config = require('./config');
if (config.credentials.client_id == null || config.credentials.client_secret == null) {
    console.error('Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables.');
    return;
}

let app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use('/api/forge/oauth', require('./routes/oauth'));
app.use('/api/forge/oss', require('./routes/oss'));
app.use('/api/forge/modelderivative', require('./routes/modelderivative'));
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); });

var server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        // any custom action here?

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            // Any custom action?

        });

        socket.on('join', function (data) {
            socket.join(data.modelView);
        });

        socket.on('leave', function (data) {
            socket.leave(data.modelView);
        });

        socket.on('statechanged', function (data) {
            socket.to(data.modelView).emit('newstate', data.state);
        });
    });
});
```

my local folder, captured below.
[image]

And this web site, https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/share-viewer-state-websockets

So how can I use app.listen when the app.listen function is inside a var type variable?

The problem part of above code.

```
var server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        // any custom action here?

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            // Any custom action?

        });

        socket.on('join', function (data) {
            socket.join(data.modelView);
        });

        socket.on('leave', function (data) {
            socket.leave(data.modelView);
        });

        socket.on('statechanged', function (data) {
            socket.to(data.modelView).emit('newstate', data.state);
        });
    });
});
```

I want the node.js run and duplicate one web app's camera view to another web app's camera view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code that references the `server` variable and configures the `io` variable outside the callback like this:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // any custom action here?

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        // Any custom action?

    });

    socket.on('join', function (data) {
        socket.join(data.modelView);
    });

    socket.on('leave', function (data) {
        socket.leave(data.modelView);
    });

    socket.on('statechanged', function (data) {
        socket.to(data.modelView).emit('newstate', data.state);
    });
});
```

It is perfectly fine to set up the socket.io server before the `.listen()` has completed.  The `server` object itself is already a proper server object that you can use as soon as `app.listen()` returns.

This then leaves the `io` variable in the outside scope where you can more easily use it from other code.

Note, using `var` is no longer preferred.  Instead, use either `let` or `const`.  I changed yours to `const`.

Comment: It's working. Thanks for very fast answer!
I changed const io = require('socket.io').listen(server)  to  const io = require('socket.io')(server) for some error.

Comment: @Taejin - Yes, `require('socket.io')(server)` is the correct syntax.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @jfriend00's great answer, here's an updated version of our official [Simple Viewer](https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/) code sample, using socket.io to share state among all connected clients (the one who adds `?presenter=1` to his URL is considered the presenter):

https://github.com/petrbroz/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs/tree/sample/state-sharing